# Use MenuBar component in a QQuickView on Windows

Tags: windows, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am building a `QML` application that must work on Windows and Mac OS X. I want to manage the menus in QML so I started using the [MenuBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-menubar.html) component in my application. I am using a `QQuickView` in C++ to display my QML elements. My menus appear properly on Mac OS X but I get nothing displayed on `Windows` and no errors in the logs.

The documentation speaks about this component being linked to `ApplicationWindow` but as it was working fine on Mac OS I was hoping it would work the same anywhere.

Is there a way to fix this on Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the way this is done in the QML `ApplicationWindow` component and found a way to display my menu on Windows. The idea/hack is to use the property `__contentItem` of the `MenuBar` component and attach it to the root element. I also do this only if the menu is not native so that it works as it did before on Mac OS X.

**TopMenu.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

MenuBar {
  Menu {
    title: "Window"
    MenuItem {
      text: "SubMenu3"
      shortcut: "Ctrl+s"
    }
    MenuItem {
      text: "SubMenu2"
      shortcut: "Ctrl+p"
    }
    MenuItem {
      text: "Preferences"
      shortcut: "Ctrl+,"
    }
  }
}
```

**RootElement.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    id: rootWindow
    width: 400
    height: 400


    Item {
        id: menuWrapper
        anchors.fill: parent

        TopMenu {
          id: myTopMenu
        }

        states: State {
          name: "hasMenuBar"
          when: myTopMenu && !myTopMenu.__isNative

          ParentChange {
              target: myTopMenu.__contentItem
              parent: rootWindow
          }

          PropertyChanges {
              target: myTopMenu.__contentItem
              x: 0
              y: 0
              width: menuWrapper.width
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `QQuickView` is not able to contain `ApplicationWindow` as a root object. 
Have you tried to use `QQmlApplicationEngine` instead of `QQuickView`?

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine("qml/untitled/main.qml");
    QObject* root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
    static_cast<QWindow*>(root)->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I faced with the same issue on Windows, and it helped me.

Comment: I'm gonna look into it but I spent a lot of time optimizing for QQuickView and this would involve a lot of rewrite. In the end it might clearly be easier to set my menus directly in C++ instead of doing this in QML. I'd rather want to fix this if possible keeping the QQuickView

Comment: Found a solution that works with QQuickView but thank you for the inputs!